# what is the best way to update an XML node value in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

My function iterates through every node of an instance of an `XMLDocument`.  It checks to see if the current node's name is in a lookup list.  If it is, it applies appropriate validation to the value of the current node.

When the validation method indicates that the value has been changed, I want to replace the value in the original document with the updated value.

I think the easiest way to achieve this might be to write out to an `XMLTextWriter` as I process each node in the original `XMLDocument`, either writing out the original or modified node and value as appropriate.  This method would rely on determining whether the current node has any children, or is a stand-alone node.

Is there a better way I could update the values in the original document?  I need to end up with the complete `XMLDocument`, but with updated node values, where appropriate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not modify the existing nodes (which ate already in the correct structure and in an XMLDocument, then re-serialise the XMLDocument? If the nodes are simple text containters then the

```
.InnerText
```

property is the one you want.

Comment: I think this might do it.  I'd always used .InnerText to Get values, but hadn't appreciated you could use it to Set values back into an XmlDocument as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know I always go back to this but this sounds like an example where clever use of apply-templates and [ExtensionObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject.aspx) in XSLT would be efficient.

That said XMLDocument is optimised for modification, so if you were going with a pure programmatic solution I would modify the object directly, not create a new Writer.